# keyerror while using smtp in python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, keyerror

```
for row in csv_reader:
    username = row ["Username"]
    pwd = row ["Password"]
    email = row["Username"]
    grades = row["Grades"]
    comments = row["Comments"]
```

**my error is: username = row ["Username"]

`KeyError: 'Username'**`

Comment: can you share the output of `print csv_reader` ? Might be the result is missing the following keys

Comment: Enter your email:
    Enter Password:
    upload excel file
    upload text format for sending mail
    Opening SMTP session
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "Emailcode.py", line 76, in <module>
    username = row['username']
    KeyError: 'username'

Comment: @satwik try adding the rest of this code into your question with an edit as the information presented here doesn't give enough to find the source of the issue. It only shows us that in the resultant dictionary there is no key corresponding to `Username`

Answer (score 0):

I think probably value named row does not contain `Username` key.
You can check all the key via `print(row)` or `print(csv_reader)`.

Make sure csv_reader is a list that contains dictionaries and `Username` key.
It looks like this:

```
csv_reader = [{"Username": "McCree", "Password": "Secret", "Grades": "100" ...}]
```

Answer (score 0):

let suppose i have a csv file which contain the data as below:

**username,password,email**

**John Smith,Pass!12,abc@email.com**

now i can read this csv file in following ways: the first one is with **csv.reader()**, and the other one is with **csv.DictReader()**.

- csv.reader() :

  ```
  import csv

  with open('filename') as csv_file:
      csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
      for row in csv_reader:
          #now we assign the username
          #username = row['usename']---this will give an error here
          username = row[0]     #this will assign the value at index 0 of row to username
  ```

as row is a list we have to access the value by there index.

- csv.DictReader()

  ```
      import csv
      with open('file_name', mode='r') as csv_file:
          csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
          for row in csv_reader:
              #now we assign the username
              username = row.get('username')
  ```

as the **csv.DictReader()** function *convert csv file data in dictionary*. so, we have to fetch a particular value with it's key:-- as in example we are doing this with **row.get('username')**.